# How to display capture screenshot into report using Python + Webdriver + nose & xunit

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, nose, xunit

How to **display** capture **screenshot** into **report** using **Python + Webdriver + nose & xunit** ?

Python script:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_google(self):


        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        assert False, "Desperately failing to capture screenshot"

    def tearDown(self):

        self.driver.save_screenshot("/tmp/screenshot.png")
        print ("/tmp/screenshot.png")
        self.driver.quit()
        unittest.TestCase.tearDown(self)
```

And please find the report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testsuite name="nosetests" tests="1" errors="0" failures="1" skip="0"><testcase classname="sample.GoogleTest" name="test_google" time="4.921"><failure type="exceptions.AssertionError" message="Desperatly failing to capture screenshot"><![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/anuj/workspace/py_sel/sample.py", line 17, in test_google
    assert False, "Desperatly failing to capture screenshot"
AssertionError: Desperatly failing to capture screenshot
]]></failure></testcase></testsuite>
```

Comment: The question is good, but you also should share some more details: what you've tried so far, problems you faced with your attempts

Comment: implemented a sample script for above question